# D3 - Setting the zoom scale of Double Click

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, zooming, translate

I've been looking around and haven't found a solid solution for setting the zoom scale of when a user double clicks the screen.

The furthest I got is by setting scaleVal as shown in the function dblclicked() shown here in the fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/helloGoodDay/62vq9h8p/3/

```
            function dblclicked()
            {
                var translate = zoom.translate(),
                    mouse = d3.mouse(this),
                    scaleOld = zoom.scale(),
                    zoomOld = Math.log(scaleOld) / Math.LN2,
                    zoomNew = d3.event.shiftKey ? Math.max(minScale + 8, Math.ceil(zoomOld) - 1) : Math.min(maxScale + 8, Math.floor(zoomOld) + 1),
                    scaleNew = Math.pow(scaleVal, zoomNew),
                    zoomDelta = scaleNew / scaleOld;

                 svg.transition()
                     .duration(350)
                     .call(zoom
                     .scale(scaleNew)
                     .translate([(translate[0] - mouse[0]) * zoomDelta + mouse[0], (translate[0] - mouse[0]) * zoomDelta + mouse[0]])
                     .event);

                 d3.event.stopImmediatePropagation();
            }
```

However, if you double click a bit more, the nodes disappear and I don't like the animation as well.

Is there a way to set the value of the zoom scale in a way that the nodes do not disappear and that the animation isn't this fidgety?

Edit: The function is from https://github.com/d3/d3/issues/1985

Comment: Do you want to set a maximum zoom value ? Because if you only reduce the zoom scale, it will always be a quite infinite zoom.

Comment: Thank you for responding. In the fiddle, the current zoom extent is from 1 to 1000. So yes I already set a maximum zoom value.

Answer (score 0):

Ok tell me if this solution suit to your problem

https://jsfiddle.net/qm6h4wm7/2/

What I did :

- reduce scale between each zoom (1)
- limit to 5 zoom in order to always have a node in view (2)

> in a way that the nodes do not disappear

```
(1) scaleNew = Math.pow(2, zoomNew)

(2) if(zoomNew<5){...}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to answer this question. Your current solution is quite similar to the one I did which was to limit the zooms and then zoom back out once they reach the maximum zoom. Our answers were a quick fix. I guess i'm looking for a solution wherein if u zoom closer the nodes won't disappear and if the solution can be done without the animation.

Comment: Sorry I think I don't understand you when you say "nodes won't disappear". if you block maximum zoom, they won't disappear...no? For the animation effect it seems you want to call scroll wheel effect on double clic event, no ? Have you tried to do it ?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I understand now why the nodes disappear, it's because the zoom zooms passed the maximum extent. You're right for this example it won't disappear. I don't know how to take out the animation or change it to make it smoother. As a quick fix I have increased the duration of the animation.